# Excel — formatting to truncate zero's but keep actual value

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, suppose I have a cell with a numeric value `1,570,000,000`. I want to the cell to retain that value but truncate six zero, to show `1.57`.

For readability, I would place a label adjacent to the value:

| `1.57` | billion |

Is this possible to achieve this truncation with cell formatting or some other easy way?

Comment: Why would `1,560,000,000` truncate to `1.57` bn? I hope that's just a typo...

Comment: @SaaranshGarg yes it was a typo; I have fixed the post

Answer (score 1):

1. Select cells, click format cells
2. Go for 'Custom' format
3. Type `#,###0.000,,, "Billion"`

There it is! Simple as that!

If you need more places after decimal, just add more zeroes after the `0.000` section

[image]

Comment: Nice one you get +10 ☺